# How to compare String and Symbol in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, comparison, symbols

I've a **String** and a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) defined in Javascript with same value `Hello, Stack Overflow!`. How do I compare them for equality? All the comparisons I've tried below return false.

```js
var string="Hello, Stack Overflow!";
var symbol=Symbol("Hello, Stack Overflow!");

console.log(string == symbol);
console.log(string == symbol.toPrimitive);
console.log(string == symbol.toString);
console.log(string == symbol.toStringTag);
console.log(string === symbol);
console.log(string === symbol.toPrimitive);
console.log(string === symbol.toString);
console.log(string === symbol.toStringTag);
```

Comment: A symbol does not have the *value* `Hello, Stack Overflow!`. Do you mean its *description* is set to that string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert the string to symbol then perform the comparison.

```
console.log(Symbol(string).toString() == symbol.toString())
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Symbol() will always return a unique value
You can use it slightly differently as below

Symbol.keyFor(Symbol.for("Hello, Stack Overflow!"))== "Hello, Stack Overflow!"; // True

Please read more 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol

Comment: There's no other better solution? The **symbol** definition is not at all used in this comparison, only the **string** is used.